# qual atalho para utilizar ≠ no javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Qual seria o atalho para usar ≠  no java script? pois estou tentando com ALT+8800 porem aparece `
tentei copiar da internet mas o vscode diz que o caractere é invalido.

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer com esse caractere? Poderia [edit] a pergunta e colocar um [mcve]? Ou pelo menos uma explicação mais detalhada do que vc precisa (por exemplo, quer só imprimir esse caractere na tela, ou fazer alguma outra coisa, etc)

Comment: Se isso é o que eu penso que é, não passa de uma opção visual do VSC para alterar o `!=` ou `!==` para esse caractere que é "supostamente mais legível". Existem opções similares para transformar um `=>` numa seta mesmo também. Todas essas alterações são apenas visuais, e os carateres escritos no código continuam a ser os mmesmos.

Comment: entao podeira ficar assim? const modalTrigger = (productId) => {
    const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')

    if (productId ≠  null) {
        const produto = produtos.filter( produto => produto.id = productId )[0]
    }

    if (produto ≠ null) {
        modal.querySelector('#title').value = produto.title
    }

    modal.classList.contains('hide') == true ? modal.classList.remove('hide') : modal.classList.add('hide')

Comment: ou assim const modalTrigger = (productId) => {
    const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')

    if (productId !== null) {
        const produto = produtos.filter( produto => produto.id = productId )[0]
    }

    if (produto !== null) {
        modal.querySelector('#title').value = produto.title
    }

    modal.classList.contains('hide') == true ? modal.classList.remove('hide') : modal.classList.add('hide')

Comment: No JavaScript só existe `!==`, o `≠` não é um operador válido. Use `!==` e pronto. Se o seu editor está mostrando `≠`, pode ser o que o Isac disse no comentário acima: é apenas uma "dica" visual que o editor faz (mas se abrir o arquivo em outro editor ainda estará o `!==` lá, o VSC só muda a visualização, mais nada).

Comment: Ok, problema resolvido. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

≠ e mesma coisa que !==
Se quer utilizar como comparativo !==
Se quer utilizar como string ele aceita ≠. Exemplo:
if(variavel !== 0){
console.log(variavel +"≠ 0");
}else{
console.log(variavel +"= 0");
}

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: const modalTrigger = (productId) => {
    const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')

    if (productId ≠  null) {
        const produto = produtos.filter( produto => produto.id = productId )[0]
    }

    if (produto ≠ null) {
        modal.querySelector('#title').value = produto.title
    }

    modal.classList.contains('hide') == true ? modal.classList.remove('hide') : modal.classList.add('hide')

Comment: mas poderia ficar assim?